# javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException Java application with Active directory

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

We have a java application that has multiple threads and that connects to an active directory application to read the data.  But most of time, some thread (not all) fails with exception:

> "javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 12 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090753, comment: Error processing control, data 0, v1db1 ];"  when getting next page of result (pagesize = 1000)

I googled and found that we should use only one context through the search. We have done the same thing, we are using the same context to get next page, but failing with the exception. Our domain controller is windows server 2008 r2. Is it related to domain controller or are we missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution as we are passing control for sorting of data on attribute CN. The sorting control while searching on DC is not supported once we disabled sorting it worked.